# How to update only one table for model from database with Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

I have a model generated from db with Entity Framework. When I have any change in database, I update model from database to get the change in model. But this update is applied to all entities (tables) included in model.

Now I add a new column in a table Tab1. I don't want to update model from database as some other changes that I don't want to include in model. I can add the new property in model for entity Tab1 manually. then it caused mapping error.

So I need to update `Model.Store` for the table to include the new column. It means I want to update model only for `Tab1`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The EDMX file is an XML file that is a combination of 3 different parts that make up the whole thing. If you right-click on your EDMX file and choose "Open with... XML Editor" you'll see the 3 different sections:

- `<edmx:ConceptualModels>`
- `<edmx:StorageModels>`
- `<edmx:Mappings>`

These sections can be edited manually, at your own risk! :-)
That way you can modify only what you need to.

Note that it's also possible to generate CSDL, SSDL & MSL files rather than having them embedded in the binary file, by changing the "Meta Artifact Processing" property of your model to "Copy to Output Directory".

If you don't want to do this manually, there's the [Huagati DBML/EDMX tool](http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/), it is free and you can download it from [huagati official site](http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/) or from [visual studio gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a0dcf911-8ac1-46d9-84be-e6b999c7141b), which is a Visual Studio plugin that allows you to select what changes need to be done.

Comment: thanks you. I do it manually. So there is no way do it automatically like "update from database" for single object.

Comment: The only way I know is using this: [Huagati DBML/EDMX tool](http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/). By the way, I'm not the guy who made it!  ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the link to Huagati. Very helpful! Here is a demo video http://huagati.blogspot.com/2010/07/introducing-model-comparer-for-entity.html

Comment: Thanx a tonne for this. Its pretty easy to update the xml if one has the idea about mappings.

Comment: Is there anything like Huagati tool that supports new versions? We got great mileage out of that tool until we upgraded to a new version of EF.

Comment: This whole "manual" edit need really means is EF is TERRIBLE technology for anything past a very trivial level of database/model size.

Answer (score 5):

I use following (Conditional) trick.  **This could be done only when no Table depends on the table which you want to update.**

1. Delete the table which needs to be updated.
2. Right click on Model and select 'Update Model From Database'. The Table would be shown in the tab 'Add'.  Select this table and Update the model.

**Precaution** : If other existing tables have changes in them, EF would update these changes as well.

Comment: Hmm.. EF would update columns in other tables as well. Don't know how to avoid this. :-(

Comment: This is the easiest way.  Delete the table, then add it back.

Answer (score -25):

There is way of doing it automatically.

right click edmx file > update model from data base > Refresh tab > Tables > select the table(you want to update) and press finish that's it.

Comment: I don't think this is right/  From what I can tell, it refreshes everything on the refresh tab.  That's the OP's original problem (and mine).

Comment: This does not solve the posted question and can do more harm when refreshing the whole model.

Comment: While the UI does make it look like you can update only a single table, the result is that all tables are updated. So unfortunately, this answer is incorrect. It would be great if the editor was updated to work as described here.