# Updating the EDMX file brings in massive tables

Tags: c#, .net, edmx, edmx-designer

HI I have one table used in this code, C#. I added 2 columns to the table and now want to update the model. I right click to open the EDMX file, I put the cursor in the blue diagram, right click to update model from database, I choose refresh and select the only table that is offered, which is correct. Then finish.

Yet it brings onto the display in addition like 50 + tables from this database and have to manually delete with 2 passes. Why is this happening?

I have more adding coming up soon as well.

Comment: what version of entity framework is this?  From my "Refresh" view, there is no options to select entities to update, it just updates all of the entities that are already in your model.

Comment: I noticed now in the diagram file it has all the tables of the database, is this a problem?

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985552/how-to-update-only-one-table-for-model-from-database-with-entity-framework

Comment: I see. But is it safe to keep all the tables like that in my code? in the EDMX.diagram like this <EntityTypeShape EntityType="IBSModel.SFTPmap" Width="1.5" PointX="0.75" PointY="0.75" />